# PHP Form Data Validation + Redirect

Tags: php, forms, validation, redirect

I have a form I need to create in PHP that needs to validate the data that is entered and send it through if everything is in order. It took me awhile to get to it but it redirects if all forms are filled out properly. However, the reception page does not get the data from the form page. Can I apply two actions to the form? How else do I send the data both to itself ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) and another page? I am getting the Undefined index error on all my variable definitions in the reception page.

Here is the code for the form page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Jonathan DeMars
    4/20/2017
    http://chelan.highline.edu/~jon_demars3/116/magazine.html
    -->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GQ - Subscription</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Register to GQ">
        <meta name="author" content="CSCI 116 Student: Jonathan DeMars">

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              type="text/css"
              href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <?php
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ?>

<body>

<h1>Register to GQ</h1>
<p>GQ or "Gentleman's Quarterly" is an international monthly men's magazine based in New York City. The publication focuses on fashion, style,
and culture for men; though articles on food, movies, fitness, sex, music, travel, sports, technology,
and books are also featured.</p>
<hr>
<br>
<p><strong>Please complete the following form:</strong></p>
<?php
$firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $addressErr = $cityErr = $zipcodeErr = $monthsErr = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $address = $city = $zipcode = $months = "";



if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
  $last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
  $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
  $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
  $zipcode = test_input($_POST["zipcode"]);
  $months = test_input($_POST["months"]);
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["first_name"])) {
    $firstnameErr = "First name is required";
  } else {
    $first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name)) {
  $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
}
  }
  if (empty($_POST["last_name"])) {
    $lastnameErr = "Last name is required";
  } else {
    $last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name)) {
  $lastnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
}
  }

  if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
    $addressErr = "Address is required";
  } else {
    $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
    $cityErr = "City is required";
  } else {
    $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
  $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
}
  }

  if (empty($_POST["zipcode"])) {
    $zipcodeErr = "Zipcode is required";
  } else {
    $zipcode = test_input($_POST["zipcode"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{5})(-[0-9]{4})?$/i",$zipcode)) {
        $zipcodeErr = "Please enter a valid zipcode.";
    }
  }

    if (empty($_POST["months"])) {
    $monthsErr = "You must subscribe for 1 or more months.";
  } else {
    $months = test_input($_POST["months"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]*$/",$months)) {
        $monthsErr = "Must enter a valid number.";
    }
  }

}

 if($firstnameErr == "" && $lastnameErr == "" && $addressErr == "" && $cityErr == "" && $zipcodeErr == "" &&  $monthsErr == ""){

    header('Location: magazinevalidation_post.php');
    exit();
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" size="15" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>" <span class="error">* <?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" size="15" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>"  <span class="error">* <?php echo $lastnameErr;?></span></p>
    <br>

    <p>Address: <input type="text" name="address" size="20" value="<?php echo $address;?>"  <span class="error">* <?php echo $addressErr;?></span></p>

    <p>City: <input type="text" name="city" size="15" value="<?php echo $city;?>" <span class="error">* <?php echo $cityErr;?></span> </p>

    <p>State: <select name="state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <p>Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zipcode" size="4" value="<?php echo $zipcode;?>"  <span class="error">* <?php echo $zipcodeErr;?></p>
    <br>
    <br>

    <p>How many months would you like to subscribe? <input type="text" name="months" size="1" value="<?php echo $months;?>" <span class="error">* <?php echo $monthsErr;?></span></p>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>

    <p><a href="index.html">Return to index page</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the reception page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GQ - Thank you!</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Thank you for Registering to GQ">
        <meta name="author" content="CSCI 116 Student: Jonathan DeMars">

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              type="text/css"
              href="styles.css">

    </head>

<?php
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<body>
<?php
echo "<h1>Order Summary</h1><hr>";

define("TAX", "0.10");
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
$months = $_POST['months'];
$name = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
$monthlyrate = 9.99;
$subtotal = $months * $monthlyrate;
$taxtotal = $subtotal * TAX;
$grandtotal = $subtotal + $taxtotal;

print "<p><strong>$name</strong></p>";
print "<strong>$address</strong><br>";
print "<strong>$city, $state $zipcode</strong><br>";
print "<p>Your Subscription: <strong>$months months</strong></p>";
print "Monthly Payments: <strong>$$subtotal</strong><br>";
print "Tax:";
echo "<strong> $";
echo round($taxtotal, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
echo "</strong>";
print "<br>Total:";
echo "<strong> $";
echo round($grandtotal, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
echo "</strong>";


print "<div><p>Thank you, $name, for your subscription. You will recieve your first copy of GQ within the week!
</p></div>";

?>

    <p><a href="index.html">Return to index page</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use AJAX to send data to as many processing files as you want. But I don't think you can set the action attribute to more than just one page. In any case, if you want your method to send the data to the same page (just reload with the POST data) you can simply set it to empty like `action=""` and that's enough. But yeah, I think you can simply use AJAX to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session for pass the data to another form. Before redirect set the values in session after you can access these data in form2 with using session variables.
**$_SESSION - probably best way**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name; 
$_SESSION['address'] = $address;
$_SESSION['city'] = $city;
$_SESSION['address'] = $address;
$_SESSION['zipcode'] = $zipcode;
$_SESSION['months'] = $months;
header('Location: magazinevalidation_post.php');
exit();
```

In magazinevalidation_post.php file you can access the value with

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['first_name'];
echo $_SESSION['last_name'] 
echo $_SESSION['address'];
echo $_SESSION['city'];
echo $_SESSION['address'];
echo $_SESSION['zipcode'];
echo $_SESSION['months'];
?>
```